# Order events by event time from multiple Kafka topics

Tags: events, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

We are trying to order events by event time that we consume from three Kafka topics. Each source topic has three partitions and we set the Flink parallelism also to three. After reading the events from Kafka, we map each event into a generic format and union them. Lastly, we key they unioned stream by a shared `eventID` and try to order them using a ProcessFunction as explained [here](https://www.ververica.com/blog/replayable-process-functions-time-ordering-and-timers).

[image: Flink High Level Jobgraph]

We assign the event time to the events like the following:

```
WatermarkStrategy<String> watermarkStrategy = 
    WatermarkStrategy.<String>forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ofMinutes(10))
    .withTimestampAssigner(new SerializableTimestampAssigner<String>() {
        @Override
        public long extractTimestamp(String element, long recordTimestamp) {
            ...
        }
    });

KafkaSource<String> topic = KafkaSource.<String>builder()
    .setBootstrapServers("...")
    .setTopics("my_topic")
    .setGroupId("my-group")
    .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.earliest())
    .setValueOnlyDeserializer(new SimpleStringSchema())
    .build();

DataStreamSource<String> sourceStream = env.fromSource(topic, watermarkStrategy, "Kafka Source");
```

The (simplified) process function looks like this:

```
public class OrderProcessFunction extends KeyedProcessFunction<String, Tuple2<LocalDateTime, String>, Tuple2<LocalDateTime, String>> {

    private transient MapState<Long, List<Tuple2<LocalDateTime, String>>> queueState = null;

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration config) {
        TypeInformation<Long> key = TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<Long>() {});
        TypeInformation<List<Tuple2<LocalDateTime, String>>> value = TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<List<Tuple2<LocalDateTime, String>>>() {});
        queueState = getRuntimeContext().getMapState(new MapStateDescriptor<>("events-by-timestamp", key, value));
    }

    @Override
    public void processElement(Tuple2<LocalDateTime, String> event,
                               KeyedProcessFunction<String, Tuple2<LocalDateTime, String>, Tuple2<LocalDateTime, String>>.Context ctx,
                               Collector<Tuple2<LocalDateTime, String>> out) throws Exception {

        TimerService timerService = ctx.timerService();
        if (ctx.timestamp() > timerService.currentWatermark()) {

            List<Tuple2<LocalDateTime, String>> listEvents = queueState.get(ctx.timestamp());
            if (isEmpty(listEvents)) {
                listEvents = new ArrayList<>();
            }

            listEvents.add(event);
            queueState.put(ctx.timestamp(), listEvents);
            timerService.registerEventTimeTimer(ctx.timestamp());
        } else {
            // Event considered late, write to side output to debug
            ctx.output(sideOutputLateEventsProcessFunction, event);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimer(long timestamp, KeyedProcessFunction<String, Tuple2<LocalDateTime, String>, Tuple2<LocalDateTime, String>>.OnTimerContext ctx,
                        Collector<Tuple2<LocalDateTime, String>> out) throws Exception {
        queueState.get(timestamp).forEach(out::collect);
        queueState.remove(timestamp);
    }
}
```

The topics already have historic events from the last half year, which we also want to order. One topic in particular has way more than the other two, which to our understanding would cause the process function to buffer all events until watermarks have arrived from each Flink Kafka Source.

However, when we start the Flink job, only a few events are correctly ordered, but most of them (for all streams) are quickly considered late in the ProcessFunction and therefore dropped.

We have the following questions:

- We understand from the [Flink Kafka Source documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.18/docs/dev/datastream/event-time/generating_watermarks/#watermark-strategies-and-the-kafka-connector) that the watermarks are computed across alls partitions. That would mean that Flink would first need to process at least one event per partition after which a watermark for that partition is generated. The Flink Kafka Source would the emit a watermark that is the minimum across all partition watermarks. Is that correct? Does this also work with a `SerializableTimestampAssigner`, because it currently seems it doesn't.
- What's the best way to debug the event time / watermarking mechanism of the Flink Kafka Source to understand why the processing function drops most of the events? We are currently using side outputs for the late data and the Flink WebUI for the watermarks.

Thank you!

Comment: Which version of Flink are you using? If it's recent enough, you can call the `withWatermarkAlignment()` method when defining your watermark strategy, and this could mitigate some of the impact of having one topic be much bigger than the others. See https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/event-time/generating_watermarks/#watermark-alignment

Comment: I'm assuming data in any given topic is evenly distributed across partitions, so that you don't have say one partition with data that is much older than the other partitions, right?

Comment: Ah, I missed to mention that we are using 1.15 and have tried to use the Alignment Groups, but the Kafka Sources are then not making any progress at all. We assumed it's due to the fact that the alignment were still in beta and only made production ready in 1.18, but we will double check this.

Regarding the partitions, yes, we assume that we have a somewhat even distribution across partitions, no heavy skew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We realised that we are facing [this bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-28975) within Flink that was only  fixed in later versions.

We configured idleness for all Flink Kafka consumers, but the bug incorrectly marked the stream consumers as idle. This led to the many late events in the process function.

Answer (score 1):

In your `processElement()` method, you need to calculate a "window start time" from the incoming event. This is based on your window size that you need in order to properly arrange events by timestamp. Currently you build a list that's keyed by the explicit event timestamp, so no windowing happens.

You also want to create the timer only when you're adding a new entry to the map, and set the timer's time to be the window start time + the window size, so that it fires when the window is expected to be "complete".

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for taking the time!

We don't build up an explicit window, but instead store the event in the Flink state until the watermark has passed the event's event time. We expect that once the watermark for the event time passes, the onTimer method will be called, which will then release all stored events which were stored since then. True, it would mean that we have many timers. Any downsides with this approach?

Comment: If you want to order the events, you have to use a window. Related, a keyBy() can/will scramble the ordering of events read from Kafka, due to network activity. Watermarks are only generated every 200ms (by default). And you can't depend on the order of timers firing when a watermark arrives.